# Cron job through Kohana Controller

Tags: php, cron, kohana, command-line-interface

This is how my controller looks like

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Cron extends Controller {

    public function before() {

        if(!Kohana::$is_cli) ;
    }

    public function action_index() {
        $myFile = "C:\cron.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, "\n");
        $stringData = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }
}

?>
```

I run the script through a command line using this

```
php "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\www\myweb\index.php" --uri=cron/index
```

where *cron* is the controller and *index* is a function.

***Now what I need is to run the script every x-minute***

When I run the script through the browser, it is only that time that the *C:\cron.txt* is modified.
I heart by putting this

```
public function before() {

        if(!Kohana::$is_cli) ;
    }
```

was to avoid any access via the browser ?
So,
1. How can I deny access from the browser ?
2. How can I make the code running every x-minute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these two links to get what you need.[Cron Jobs in Kohana 3](http://www.coderelic.com/2011/10/creating-cron-jobs-in-kohana-3-x-is-a-piece-of-cake/)

A module that can help [kohana-cron](https://github.com/cbandy/kohana-cron)
[Kohana Minion](https://github.com/kohana/minion)

Answer (score 1):

To check if the script accessed from command-line, use `php_sapi_name() == 'cli'` Use it to detect whether your script accessed from cli or browser. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) for detail.

To make the code run every X minute, create a new task scheduler to run a .bat file with your command-line in it. Make sure that you call php executable using full-path, e.g `C:\apache\php.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\www\myweb\index.php" --uri=cron/index`

cheers

Answer (score 1):

since it's windows, it's not actually "cron". You have two choices:

- Set the `action_index` to execute a endless loop, and then check for the desired interval, and `usleep` for a while to save CPU cycles, like 100, so it doesn't take all your processing power
- Use the Windows Scheduler to run your script every time.

Your code, in `before()` should be

```php
function before(){
  if (!Kohana::$is_cli) { throw new HTTP_Exception_403; // Denied };
}
```

Make sure you are dealing with exceptions properly. Or you can just make the screen blank on 403 exceptions. You may pass only `--uri="cron"` to the PHP command line, since the the `index` part is always the default action (in the default `Route::set` inside your bootstrap)

You must catch the exception in your `index.php`:

```php
 $request = Request::factory();

 try
 {
      $response = $request->execute();
 }
 catch (HTTP_Exception $exc)
 {
    $response = Request::factory('your/error')->execute();
    // or $response = Response::factory()->status(403)->body('<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>');
 }

 echo
   $response     
   ->send_headers()
   ->body();
```

Comment: HTTP_Exception_403 gives me an ExceptionError ,normally it has to display the 403 error page

Comment: you must change your index.php to catch those exceptions and do the appropriate action, like display a blank page or either a simple 403 page, like `<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>`. If you are using Kohana 3.3 you should use minion for CLI stuff. i've updated the code for the `index.php` part of catching the exception